# Mongo Query $inc with $set

Tags: database, mongodb

I am getting error when i tried this

```
db.getCollection("errors").update({
    _id: ObjectId("63ff2a2351c56c92e265cf4c")
}, [
    {
        $inc: {
            'tryCount': 1
        }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            status: {
                $cond: {
                    if : {
                        $gte: ["tryCount", 4]
                    },
                    then: 'failed',
                    else : '$status',
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

What is the best way for solve this?

I need to change status when tryCount bigger than 3

Comment: if i use "update" no error message but nothing changed or incremented. when i use updateMany unrecognized pipeline stage name $inc

Comment: sory, if i use "update" all columns changed to null value

Comment: `update` doesn't support to use `format` aggregation pipeline yet, cmiiw. so you need to use `updateOne` instead.

Comment: You are mixing update operators with aggregation pipeline operators/stages.

Comment: but i need update Many rows, search query only for example

Comment: following your query, you were updated one row, and `updateOne` can update multiple fields as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You run

```
db.getCollection("errors").update(
   { <filter> }, 
   [ <aggregation pipeline> ]
)
```

Problem is `$inc` is an [Update Operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/update/) which is available only in update operations, for example, in `db.collection.updateMany()` and `db.collection.findAndModify()` but not in [Aggregation Pipelines](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/).

Try this:

```
db.getCollection("errors").updateOne( 
// or db.getCollection("errors").updateMany(
   { _id: ObjectId("63ff2a2351c56c92e265cf4c") },
   [
      {
         $set: {
            tryCount: { $add: ["$tryCount", 1] }
         }
      },
      {
         $set: {
            status: {
               $cond: {
                  if: { $gte: ["tryCount", 4] },
                  then: 'failed',
                  else: '$status',
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
);
```